# Error and stack trace messages are getting cut off in the Azure DevOps pipeline test results

Tags: azure-devops

I am running some tests in azure pipelines which generate a xml report. The report is visible under the 'tests' tab. Failed test cases contains a huge error message and a stack trace which gets cut off inside that error message box. Is there any way I can see the full message no matter how long it is?

Attached is the screen shot for that page in azure devops to convey better understanding.

[image: error message cut off snap]

Comment: You can also use [Publish artifact task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) to upload the test result file. So you can download it and check the original test results file.

Comment: That is already implemented. But I was hoping if the user can see the results directly from this message box. Currently the limit of this message is 4000 which is very less.

Comment: Where do you get the hint that the limit of the message is 4000? The message from web portal? Could you share the screenshot where the 4000 comes here so that I can check for you.

Comment: I logged a ticket on Microsoft support website. There they told me the limit of 4k an after that they asked to log a new feature request for the same. Here is the link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1124718/increase-the-4000-character-limit-for-the-test-res.html

Comment: I also submitted an issue to Microsoft's Azure Pipelines Tasks GitHub repository: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/16696